# How can I generate the SQL query using SQL::Abstract?

Tags: sql, perl

How do I generate the `WHERE` clause for this query using [SQL::Abstract](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SQL%3a%3aAbstract):

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id =
>   111 AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(type,
>   '1,2,3,4') AND status = 'pending';

What's the proper way to include conditions like `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(type, '1,2,3,4')`?

Answer (score 5):

See the [not_bool](http://search.cpan.org/dist/SQL-Abstract/lib/SQL/Abstract.pm#Unary_operators:_bool) unary operator option:

```
use SQL::Abstract;

my $sql = SQL::Abstract->new;

my $where = {
    id => 111,
    status => 'pending',
    -not_bool => "FIND_IN_SET(type, '1,2,3,4')",
};

my ($query, @bind) = $sql->select( 
    'table',
    'count(*)',
    $where,
);
```

This is how `$query` looks:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE ( ( (NOT FIND_IN_SET(type, '1,2,3,4')) 
AND id = ? AND status = ? ) )
```

Answer (score 3):

This code generates the `WHERE` clause:

```
my $sql = SQL::Abstract->new;    

my %where = (
    id => 111,
    -nest => \"NOT FIND_IN_SET(type, '1,2,3,4')",
    status => 'pending',
);

my ($stmt, @bind) = $sql->where(\%where, \@order);
```

Comment: I can't find any documentation for -nest in SQL::Abstract.  How did you know to use this?

Answer (score 2):

FIND_IN_SET isn't standard SQL, so SQL::Abstract doesn't have support for it. You can however put any [literal SQL](https://metacpan.org/dist/SQL-Abstract/view/lib/SQL/Abstract.pm#Literal-SQL) into an SQL::Abstract query. I expect your solution lies down that route.

Answer (score -3):

Take a look at: DALMP

> Database Abstraction Layer for MySQL using PHP
>
> 0% fat and extremely easy to use. Only connect to database when needed.

http://code.google.com/p/dalmp/