# sql abstract in mathematica

Tags: sqlite, wolfram-mathematica, abstraction

I am using mathematica package to access and work with sqlite database.
Here is an example of sql abstraction ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913659/how-can-i-generate-the-sql-query-using-sqlabstract)). Does Mathematica suppoort sql abstraction, and any idea how to implement it (using similar query as in the link)